# Some queries regarding serializable transactions?

Tags: java, oracle

I have read committed isolation can provide considerably more concurrency than serializable isolation level.

My Question here is  **How Read committed isolation provides more concurrency than serializable?**. A brief scenario would be a great help

Question:- Say two transactions tran1 and tran2 begin(when i say transaction begin, here it mean  transaction begins when they fire some query **Right?**) at time t1. If tran1 updates  the row1 at time t2 and later at time t3 tran2 fetches the same row it wont get the updated row done by tran1 .**Right?** I said it  because tran1  and tran2 will the present the result from state of data which was present at time t1.**Correct? Does transaction take the snapshot of complete database when it begins?**

I have read that coding serializable transactions requires extra work by the application developer to check for the "Cannot serialize access" error and to undo and retry the transaction. **Not sure when developer will get “Cannot serialize access” error? Will we get the same error in below scenario**

Say two transactions tran1 and tran2 begin at time t1. If tran1 updates the row1  and commit at time t2 and later at time t3 tran2 updates and commits the same row1. Will it throw the “Cannot serialize access” error in this case? **If yes Does oracle maintain the version internally in case of serializable transactions so that it gets to know row has been updated by user?**

Comment: Oracle doesn't really have true serializable transactions. Oracle uses multi-version concurrency control, which means you can get most of the benefits of serializable transactions for a fraction of the cost in a traditional lock-oriented database. I don't know enough about this to write a real answer, though, sorry.

Comment: ***`Does transaction take the snapshot of complete database when it begins?`*** Just think of a (rather medium in size) 1GB database and just (a few) 1000 transactions starting per minute. Do you know of a box that can take **1TB per minute** snapshots?

Comment: @ ypercube . Agreed it wont be taking snapshot exactly. But it will be similar kind of stuff. That is i am looking for ?

Comment: yes, you need to manage versioning yourself, I think what you are talking about is how to handle concurrency, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455726/handling-the-concurrent-request-while-persisting-in-oracle-database/7460154#7460154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm) docs on isolation levels and data concurrency.

Comment: hi tbone, after going thru this and various other artciles, i have come up with these doubts.It would be great help if you can throw some light on above.