# Ensuring select statements for one user are true for another when user updates?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

How can I ensure that if user-a manually updates some of his information when user-b is accessing user-a's data, that user-b accessing the information gets the correct updated information and not the old stale data for user-a.

I understand transaction are good and row level locking, I just want to make sure I am doing it correct!

When updating user-a's information I am using,

```
$dbc -> beginTransaction();
$dbc -> query("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE id = " . $user['id'] . " FOR UPDATE LIMIT 1");
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET name = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['name']));
$dbc -> commit();
```

Using the above does this lock the user-a's data so that when user-b gets his data for user-a using,

```
$q = $dbc -> ("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_GET['id']));
```

He will get the correct updated data? Or do I need to use a transaction when getting user-a's data for user-b??

I am a little confused by all this locking and stuff, as you can probably tell?!?

Thanks

Comment: Rows affected will be **write**-locked as long as the update lasts. Will userB get the right data? Depends on the moment of their access to the data. You must be aware that concurrent access mean "we're so close in time that it looks like it's at the same time".

Comment: Is there not a way to perform the select statement for user-b to look at user-a's info that will only do it while the row is not locked?

Comment: It would not help you as you don't know if the userA has already performed the update, do you?

Comment: I am not sure, if userA doesn't update his info then the row wouldn't get locked meaning userB would access it, but if the row is locked then userB select would have to wait, does it just mean wrapping the select in a transaction?

Comment: There's something you could use. I found it kinda aggresive buuut... well, maybe you like it. LOCK TABLES. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

To handle concurrency in a web site, where there is a disconnect between the client & database, it is common practice to have a column on each record that allows you to check it has not been updated since you last got it.

Either a last update date column or (my preference) an autoincremented version number (implemented via a trigger), you then simply need to check in your `WHERE` clause that the value you got matched the value in the record e.g:

```
UPDATE accounts SET name = ?, lastupdate=sysdate WHERE id = ? AND lastupdate = ?
```

If the lastupdate value does not match, and therfore you can't update the record, you can assume the data has been updated by someone else and handle the exception accordingly.

This works well for systems where ovelapping updates are rare.

I prefer to use triggers, as the concurrency value is maintened for you.
(the only downside is you have to requery the data if you want to re-update the same record, that is until mysql implements the RETURNING clause)

see: [Handling the concurrent request while persisting in oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455726/handling-the-concurrent-request-while-persisting-in-oracle-database/7460154#7460154)