# People booking for an event, How do I properly restrict the maximum number of bookings? (concurrency)

Tags: postgresql, symfony, concurrency

I guess this is a classic concurrency question.

I have people signing up to participate in an event. The event can handle a maximum number of participants.

This is a Symfony application with a PostgreSQL database.

What's the best way to ensure that the event is not overbooked?

Let's say I have entities called Event, Person and Booking.  Booking has one to many relationships with Person and Event.

I display a page about the event. I count the current bookings and show a "Book now" button if count is less than the max.

Here's some psuedocode of how I've done this previously:

On the action for the Book now button:

```
Count bookings
if count >= max
  return "Sorry, this event is full"
else
  Create booking
  Flush entity manager

  Count bookings again

  if count > max
     Delete booking
     return "Sorry, this event is full"
  endif
```

endif

I think this method is safe but not ideal. I think it could result in two people booking when there is one space left and both being rejected.  The real world chance of that happening is probably close to zero and I guess the users will try again but ... it would be nice to do this correctly.

Is there a better way to do this?

I've read this: [Handling the concurrent request while persisting in oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455726/handling-the-concurrent-request-while-persisting-in-oracle-database) and a similar question I asked a few months ago. It seems that optimistic locking is a good strategy when maximum bookings = 1 such as an airline seat.  In that case I probably wouldn't have Booking entity at all. Event would just have a Person or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the doctrine docs [Concurrency and Transactions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html), there are a few options that you could use.

I would agree that optimistic locking is probably the way to go, but you wouldn't have to change your current logic.  Just add a new `version` field (type `serial` is best) to the entity you want to insert into, and when you do your initial SELECT, you pass in the unique version number.  Then when you insert, if the version has changed, you know that someone else has already booked and the insert will not happen.

The docs have some good examples there for [Optimistic Locking](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking)

UPDATE

Optimistic locking will work when updating the entity.  For inserting a new entity, transactions will be the best bet.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand optimistic locking but I don't see how it applies when adding new rows to a table which is what happens when I make a booking. Optimistic locking seems to be useful when updating an existing row. If the version has changed since you last read it then you know that someone else has updated it. I don't see how to use that to restrict the number of rows I can have in my Booking table with a specific event_id value.  That seems like a different problem.

Comment: Transactions are probably the way to go but I think I need to be concerned with isolation level. i.e., can I see other users' bookings when I count? Do I even have control of that within Symfony / Doctrine?  I'm wondering how others have done this within Symfony.

Comment: you are right, I misunderstood the question.  Optimistic locking is for updating an entity.  I don't quite understand what you mean - `can I see other users' bookings when I count?`

Comment: My understanding of transactions and isolation levels is not as good as it could be but somehow I need to ask "Is this event fully booked?". The obvious way to do that is SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM Booking WHERE event_id = ? to count bookings. If it's < max then I go ahead and INSERT INTO Booking but I need to protect against someone else doing the same which I guess means I need to do another SELECT COUNT(\*) before I commit. I think isolation levels affect whether or not I'll see other uncommitted bookings. Maybe I'm overthinking this and there is a better way.

Comment: read section 13.2.3 of this article: [Postgresql Isolation levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html), it might help you wrap your head around what is possible

Comment: I've read that before and again now. I think I would need read-uncommitted which seems to be not really possible with PostgreSQL. If it was and I could see other's pending bookings while I'm within my transaction and decide to rollback, how is that really much different to the pseudocode I described in my question? I guess I'm coming to the conclusion that to do this properly is really quite complicated even though it seems like very common requirement, e.g., booking student places in a class of limited size etc.

Comment: Serializable isolation level says `This level emulates serial transaction execution, as if transactions had been executed one after another, serially, rather than concurrently`, so this is exactly what you want.

Comment: I guess you're correct, thanks. The predicate locking that PostgreSQL does for serializable looks good. It doesn't delay other transactions.  I would start a transaction, do the count and proceed if < max. Commit will fail if another transaction happens that would change the count. I guess it will fail if someone cancels a booking which is not ideal because there is still space available for my booking to succeed but ... I can do another count and retry if the count has gone down. I'd like to wait a few days for any other answers.

Comment: Optimistic locking also works for inserting a new child entity. You just make sure you always increment the version on the parent entity too. That way, two inserts will conflict on the parent entity lock.

Comment: I was wondering about that although I'm trying to get the sequence clear in my mind. I would get the parent entity, insert the child, update something on the parent so that its version changes, then attempt to flush. If the parent has been changed by someone else doing the same thing, the whole transaction will fail and I can catch the OptimisticLockException. Somehow I feel more comfortable with that than the serial transaction. It seems like a more gentle solution.